# How to open word application fullscreen from php

Tags: php, com, ms-word

Can I force php com class to open word application in full screen?

now it opens word icon on task bar but that is not very visual if many files are open.

```
$word=new COM("word.application") or Die("Cannot start word for you");
$word->documents->Open($archive_file);
$word->Activate();
$word->visible = 1;
```

I am using this code now but all I can get is a blinking icon on taskbar.
I tried activate and visible methods but it still wont open the window

Comment: Try setting `Visible` as the first thing you do after opening Word, before opening the document or calling `Activate()`.

Comment: nope, does not work either

Answer (score 0):

found a solution that works for me

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell"); 
$obj = $WshShell->Run('cmd /c "'.$archive_file.'"', 1, false);
```